# question about the class and member function

Tags: c++, class, member

I have a question about below code(c++)
its just one line.

```
if (mkvparser::EBMLHeader().Parse(m_reader, pos))
```

here mkvparser is the namespace, EBMLHeader is in the mkvparser.

EBMLHeader() means the consturctor, after constructing EBMLHeader without parameter, 
then access the Parse function??

is this shortcut of below two lines?

```
mkvparser::EBMLHeader ebmlclass();

ebmlclass.parse(m_reader, pos)
```

am I right?

please explain this code.

total code is in the below link.
https://github.com/zaps166/libsimplewebm/blob/master/WebMDemuxer.cpp

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: `mkvparser::EBMLHeader ebmlclass();` will be treated as a function declaration rather than a variable declaration. Use `mkvparser::EBMLHeader ebmlclass;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For the **first case**:

```
mkvparser::EBMLHeader ebmlclass; //No () as it has nothing to be passed in

ebmlclass.parse(m_reader, pos)
```

You are creating an `mkvparser::EBMLHeader` object then running a member function `mkvparser::EBMLHeader::parse(...)` on the object `ebmlclass`

For the **second case**:

```
mkvparser::EBMLHeader().Parse(m_reader, pos)
```

Similarily, you are creating an `mkvparser::EBMLHeader` object, however, the object is then had the member function `mkvparser::EBMLHeader::parse(...)` run. Both effectively do the same thing. However, one of them keeps the object `ebmlclass` which can be used later.

Therefore, the first case is better than if you have to use `ebmlclass` multiple times but the second case is better in terms of *readability* and *"compactness"* for a single case.

Note that for the second case, after it is run, the `mkvparser::EBMLHeader` will be destroyed as it is out of scope.

Comment: is second case is similar to staic member initialization in class?
static member is usually initialized before object creation.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. EBMLHeader() is not static, its creating an object in stack. If parse was static then you would instead run it as mkvparser::EBMLHeader::Parse(...)